# Unexpected result at summing numbers using a while loops in console application

Tags: c#, while-loop, console-application

I am trying to make a program to sum numbers until the user enter OK.
The program make the sum, but return a bad result.

i'm not sure where is my error...

```
int sum = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter number:");
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
while (Console.ReadLine() != "OK")
    {
       sum += num; 
    }
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Can you give an example of an input, what the output was and what you expected it to be?

Comment: You read in a number, then read in a second time to check for "ok". Are you accounting for that when running it? That will throw away every second number if you aren't.

Comment: you need to ReadLine() into a string that you convert... check that it's an int first too. All of that needs to be in the while loop.

Comment: and if OK is the first input, you'll get a cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

you don't keep the number the use enter in the while loop.
you need to input the readline to a variable.

```
var num = Console.Readline();
sum += num; //parse first
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `while` loop you need to update num:

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
while (Console.ReadLine() != "OK")
{
    num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    sum += num; 
}
```

Also just as a note, if you need your program to be a little safer, you can you use the following:

```
int num;
if(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num)) {
    //do something.. 
}
else {
    //do something else.. like end program, throw exception etc.
}
```

[Int32.TryParse:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion
>   succeeded

This way you can do something in the instance that the input `string` was not a valid conversion.  Example: if someone input `cat`, which can not be converted to an `int`, it would crash your program without the `TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to input the number once per iteration, and store it each time. So each value retrieved from `Console.ReadLine()` needs to be captured in an assignment statement, then converted to a number if it is not "OK".

I think you're after this:

```
int sum = 0;
string input;

Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "OK")
{
    int inputNum = Convert.ToInt32(input);
    sum += num;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
}
```

The statement `(input = Console.ReadLine()` assigns the user input to the `input` variable, then the assignment statement returns the value of `input`. Then that value is compared against `OK`.
An alternative way to get input, then check it is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
input = Console.ReadLine()
while (input != "OK")
{
    ...
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int sum = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter number:");
int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
while (sum< num)
{
     sum++;
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: Add an explanation to what you've changed. Code-only answers without explanation tend to be confusing and not useful to other readers. If you add an explanation (e.g. you used _x_, you should use _y_ instead) your answer will be more complete.